# Is there a specific rationale for the use of unconventional naming in Android's Jetpack Compose library?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

It is pretty common to name functions in modern programming languages (Kotlin, Swift, Go, Rust, Java, ...) as verbs with initial lower camel case: `doThis()`, `getThat()`, `findAnother()`, etc. Yet Jetpack Compose seems to flaunt that valuable convention which makes reading code harder by providing functions like `MaterialTheme()`, `Column()`, `Spacer()`, etc. which do not reveal the declaration intent and appear to be constructors at first glance. The big question is: why? Perhaps there is a very good reason for this.  Perhaps not.

Comment: IIRC, the rationale given in Kotlinlang Slack was that these are really widgets or other UI elements and therefore are nouns, not verbs.

Comment: they are top-level functions masquerading as widget factories.. or the other way around

Comment: One of the Jetpack Compose library developers told me on Kotlinlang Slack that writing functions with names like declareColumn() instead of Column() would be tiresome (with a smiley it should be noted) which might be the case for the library developers but as an app developer I would prefer the former since it clearly reveals my intent to readers of my code, which I believe to the the purpose of names. Secondarily, but also importantly, it complies with well established and useful conventions: is a lowerCamelCase verb.

Answer (score 0):

**If compose returns Unit**

Composable functions that return Unit are considered declarative entities that can be either present or absent in a composition and therefore follow the naming rules for classes...

```
// This function is a descriptive PascalCased noun as a visual UI element
@Composable
fun FancyButton(text: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
```

> https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md#compose-baseline

**And if the compose function returns something**

Jetpack Compose framework development and Library development MUST follow the standard Kotlin Coding Conventions for the naming of functions for any function annotated @Composable that returns a value other than Unit...

While useful and accepted outside of @Composable functions, this factory function convention has drawbacks that set inappropriate expectations for callers when used with @Composable functions.

Primary motivations for marking a factory function as @Composable include using composition to establish a managed lifecycle for the object or using CompositionLocals as inputs to the object's construction. The former implies the use of Compose's remember {} API to cache and maintain the object instance across recompositions, which can break caller expectations around a factory operation that reads like a constructor call. (See the next section.) The latter motivation implies unseen inputs that should be expressed in the factory function name.

Additionally, the mental model of Unit-returning @Composable functions as declarative entities should not be confused with a, "virtual DOM" mental model. Returning values from @Composable functions named as PascalCase nouns promotes this confusion, and may promote an undesirable style of returning a stateful control surface for a present UI entity that would be better expressed and more useful as a hoisted state object.

```
// Returns a style based on the current CompositionLocal settings
// This function qualifies where its value comes from
@Composable
fun defaultStyle(): Style {
```

> https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md#naming-composable-functions-that-return-values

*In short - if it returns Unit think about it as a fancy class and write it the same way as a class. If not - write it as a function.*